# Flexbox 6 columns equal width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to Flexbox, but thought I could use it to make a responsive navigational menu with contains 6 columns. The problem that I"m having is that it will stretch 100% of screen, but in most cases, the widths of the buttons are not equal. Is there any way that I can have the buttons equal width and still be responsive based on screen size and font size?

Refer to this for code: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1vtz3o6/)

```
.cat-bg {
    display: flex;
}
.showSingle {
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 30%;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You may use the shorthand : `flex:1;` or `flex: 0 1 30%` where the 30% is to match your `max-width:30%;` if float takes over. display:block is useless if float is also there for your fallback. https://jsfiddle.net/v1vtz3o6/5/ https://jsfiddle.net/v1vtz3o6/4/

Answer (score 1):

By default, flex'ed objects will be sized according to their contents. You can change this by adjusting the `flex-basis` property. In your case, you can make all of the columns/buttons the same size like this:

```
.showSingle {
  flex: 1;
}
```

(instead of `flex-grow: 1`)

Also note that you should remove the `float` and `display` statements, and one of the two `cursor` statements. So your final CSS for these elements should be:

```
.cat-bg {
  display: flex;
}

.showSingle {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

For what it's worth, the shorthand `flex` property in this case is equivalent to the following:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `flex-basis: 0;` to `.showSingle`.

https://jsfiddle.net/3mgr14v4/

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.cat-bg {
    display: flex;
  padding:10px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.showSingle {
    flex-basis:100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I found how to correct it:

```
.cat-bg {
 max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.showSingle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  display: block;
}
```